# Почему возникает исключение "NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()"?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

При создании `SessionFactory()` происходит ошибка. Насколько я понимаю это какая-то не совместимость, а что и как понять не могу.

Не работает код `return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

Настройки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.ivmiit.mvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.47</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Стек ошибок:

> ```
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:37 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
> INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.6.Final}
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:37 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
> INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:43 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
> INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
> WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
> INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
> INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
> INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
> INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
> Tue Sep 18 08:47:47 EEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
> сен 18, 2018 8:47:47 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
> INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1236)
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:833)
>   at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
>   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
>   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
>   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
>   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
>   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
>   at ru.ivmiit.mvc.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:9)
>   at ru.ivmiit.mvc.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:6)
>   at ru.ivmiit.mvc.utils.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:15)
>   at ru.ivmiit.mvc.utils.SessionUtil.openTransactionSession(SessionUtil.java:18)
>   at ru.ivmiit.mvc.service.CompService.getAll(CompService.java:20)
>   at MainTest.main(MainTest.java:8)
> ```

Comment: В приложенном вами участке pom.xml перечислены действительно все зависимости? `javax.persistence.Table.indexes()` относится к JPA, но его нет в списке, как и ничего другого, что могло бы подтянуть транзитивную зависимость несовместимой с Hibernate версии.

Comment: Наверно вы это имели ввиду  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Я не видел вашего проекта и не знаю конкретных требований по зависимостям, но попробуйте заменить `javax.persistence.persistence-api` на [org.hibernate.javax.persistence.hibernate-jpa-2.1-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.2.Final). И подозреваю, что вам не нужны `org.springframework.spring-jdbc` и `org.hibernate.hibernate-entitymanager`.

Answer (score 2):

Если ловите исключения подобно этому, то причина здесь очевидна - разные версии библиотек. Одни зависимости используют одну - другие другую, в итоге они не могут договориться и появляется это.

Могу посоветовать узнать в каком артифакте находиться данный класс, далее при помощи мавен выяснить кто какую версию использует, выполнив команду

```
mvn dependecy:tree
```

Затем исключив библиотеку из данной зависимости, либо изменить ее версию, чтобы она использовала библиотеку нужной версии